# Mudando a lógica - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Eu tenho vários botões do qual adiciona e remove produtos a partir de um arquivo externo, mas esse é só um detalhe. Toda vez que o botão comprar é clicado, o produto é adicionado, o botão é "trocado" para remover e todos os outros botões ficam inabilitados para o clique até que o mesmo produto seja removido a partir do botão remover.

Eu preciso mudar essa lógica para essa: Toda vez que o botão comprar é clicado, o produto é adicionado e o botão é "trocado". Porém, se outro botão comprar é clicado, o produto que foi adicionado é removido e o mesmo é adicionado no lugar dele.

**Observação: as funções `addCartao` e `removeCartaotoCart`, adicionam o removem o produto.**

**Código do botão:**

```
 <button type="button" class="button btn-cart" onclick="addCartao('<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>')" name="cartaoMensagem<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" id="cartaoMensagem<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"><span><span>Comprar</span></span></button>
 <button style="display: none;" type="button" id="cartaoMensagemRemover<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="removeCartaotoCart('<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>')" name="cartaoMensagem<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"><span><span>Remover</span></span></button>
```

**Código das requisições Ajax:**

```
function addCartao(product_id){
    $j('#cartaoMensagem'+product_id).hide();
    $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+product_id).show();
    $j.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "adiciona.php",
      data: {
        product_id: product_id
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      cache : false,
      beforeSend: function () {

      },
      success: function (retorno) {
        var button = $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+product_id);

        $j('#cartao').find(':button').not(button).attr('disabled',true);
        $j('.item-custom').append('<tr id="trAppend"><td class="a-center lc-thumbnails"><img src="' + retorno['imagem'] + '" width="50" height="50" alt="' + retorno['name'] + '"></td><td><h3 class="product-name">' + retorno['name'] + '</h3></td><td class="a-center">1</td><td class="a-right"><span class="cart-price"><span class="price"> R$ ' + retorno['price'] + '</span></span></td></tr>');
        getSubTotal();
        getGrandTotal();
      },
      complete: function () {

      },
      error: function (x,y,z) {
        alert("error");
        alert(x);
        alert(y);
        alert(z);
        window.location.reload();
        history.go(0);
        window.location.href=window.location.href;
      }
  });
}



 function removeCartaotoCart(itemId){
        $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+itemId).hide();
        $j('#cartaoMensagem'+itemId).show();
        $j.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"remove.php",
            data:{
                itemId: itemId
            },
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function(){

            },
            success: function(retorno){
                var button = $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+itemId);
                $j('#cartao').find(':button').attr('disabled',false);
                $j('.item-custom #trAppend').remove();
                getSubTotal();
                getGrandTotal();

            },
            complete: function () {

            },
            error: function (x,y,z) {
            alert("error");
            alert(x);
            alert(y);
            alert(z);
            window.location.reload();
            history.go(0);
            window.location.href=window.location.href;
          }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mudança feita no código para a mudança da lógica foi o adicionamento de uma variável para salvar o id do produto para que o mesmo seja removido se já houver um.

**Código das requisições Ajax atualizado:**

```
    var productSelected = "";
    function addCartao(product_id){
        alert(product_id);
        if( productSelected != "" ){
            removeCartaotoCart(productSelected);    // Remove the item in cart, if there is one.
          }
        $j('#cartaoMensagem'+product_id).hide();
        $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+product_id).show();
        $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+product_id).css({'background-color': '#000000'});
        $j.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "adiciona.php",
          data: {
            product_id: product_id
          },
          dataType: 'json',
          cache : false,
          beforeSend: function () {

          },
          success: function (retorno) {
            var button = $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+product_id);
            productSelected = product_id;  


            $j('.item-custom').append('<tr id="trAppend"<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>><td class="a-center lc-thumbnails"><img src="' + retorno['imagem'] + '" width="50" height="50" alt="' + retorno['name'] + '"></td><td><h3 class="product-name">' + retorno['name'] + '</h3></td><td class="a-center">1</td><td class="a-right"><span class="cart-price"><span class="price"> R$ ' + retorno['price'] + '</span></span></td></tr>');
            getSubTotal();
            getGrandTotal();
          },
          complete: function () {

          },
          error: function (x,y,z) {
            alert("error");
            alert(x);
            alert(y);
            alert(z);
            window.location.reload();
            history.go(0);
            window.location.href=window.location.href;
          }
      });
    }

    function removeCartaotoCart(itemId){
        productSelected = ""; 
        $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+itemId).hide();
        $j('#cartaoMensagem'+itemId).show();
        $j.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"remove.php",
            data:{
                itemId: itemId
            },
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function(){

            },
            success: function(retorno){
                var button = $j('#cartaoMensagemRemover'+itemId);

                $j('.item-custom #trAppend').remove();
                getSubTotal();
                getGrandTotal();
                alert("Sucess removeCartao");
            },
            complete: function () {
                alert("complete removeCartaotoCart");
            },
            error: function (x,y,z) {
            alert("error");
            alert(x);
            alert(y);
            alert(z);
            window.location.reload();
            history.go(0);
            window.location.href=window.location.href;
          }
        });
    }
```